# Spring SPEL collection projection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, collections, spring-el

A simple question on SPEL collection selection.

Look at section 10.5.17 Collection Selection on this page
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html

```
List<Inventor> list = (List<Inventor>) parser.parseExpression(
        "Members.?[Nationality == 'Serbian']").getValue(societyContext);
```

What i need is the selection 'Serbian' to come from outside and not be a fixed hard coded String.

Just for arguments sake consider that, we could get it as "**selectedNationality**" from the same society class from the same page in the link.

**Modified class with selectedNationality**

```
public class Society {
    private String name;
    public static String Advisors = "advisors";
    public static String President = "president";
    private List<Inventor> members = new ArrayList<Inventor>();
    private Map officers = new HashMap();
// new selector field
    private String selectedNationality;
......
 }
```

**New Selection**

The new selection SPEL would look like

```
List<Inventor> list = (List<Inventor>) parser.parseExpression(
        "Members.?[Nationality == selectedNationality]").getValue(societyContext);
```

When we try that the error is that "selectedNationality" is not a part of the Member object.

Does that mean that for collection selection in spring expression language we would need a hard coded String ? If yes does anyone know why ?

Comment: Why not simply `"Members.?[Nationality == '" + selectedNationality + "']"`? But why do you want to use SPEL for this in the first place?

Comment: Would that not just give me a string called selectedNationality, and not the value of selectedNationality ? The answer to Why is that just do not want to hard code anything in the el.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to do it. So the way is to use variables
see 10.5.11 Variables @ [https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html][1]

**Set Variable**

So in our case we wold do this set variable :

```
Inventor tesla = new Inventor("Nikola Tesla", "Serbian");
StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext(tesla);
context.setVariable("selectedNationality ", "Serbian");
```

**New Selection**

The new selection SPEL would look like this with **#selectedNationality**

```
List<Inventor> list = (List<Inventor>) parser.parseExpression(
        "Members.?[Nationality == #selectedNationality]").getValue(societyContext);
```

Works like a charm !